# When moving internal CSS to separate file, it works different -- now resolved

Tags: html, css

From the code below, I cut and pasted the `<style>` section into different css file by replacing the section with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">`, but it renders differently. Please tell me how do I secure original style even when I moved them into a `.css` file.

--> Now I see it works fine. Sorry for the confusion folks.

***Disclaimer: This code was generated by ChatGPT.***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Data Provider Site</title>
  <style>
    /* Add your custom styles here */
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    header {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      color: #e2b931;
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    h1 {
      margin: 0;
    }

    nav {
      background-color: #c8beb8;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    nav ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    nav ul li a {
      display: block;
      padding: 10px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #333;
    }

    nav ul li a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }

    main {
      padding: 20px;
    }

    footer {
      background-color: #333;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Data Provider Site</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <!-- Add your content here -->
    <h2>Welcome to Our Data Provider Site</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla et iaculis arcu. Duis sed nulla eu enim ullamcorper ultricies.</p>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>&copy; 2023 Your Company. All rights reserved.</p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**Original page**
[image: Original page]

**Page with separate .css file**
[image: Page with separate .css file]

**styles.css**

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #1e155e;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

main {
  padding: 20px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Temp</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Temp</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="data.html">Data</a></li>
      <li><a href="lesson.html">Lesson</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <!-- Add your content here -->
    <h2>Welcome to Our Data Provider Site</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla et iaculis arcu. Duis sed nulla eu enim ullamcorper ultricies.</p>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>&copy; 2023 . All rights reserved.</p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked in the Network Tab and in the Console Tab of the browser that the CSS is loaded when it's in a separated filed?

Comment: Please post your style.css file here

Comment: Are you sure the path to css is correct?

Comment: @gentbrika Checked, and did well.

Comment: @Pippo Yes, possibly it is. Now I reloaded the code and saw it works fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine for me. Here I have attached my working code and the screenshot generated from the code.

You can try clearing the browser cache. Sometimes browser cache is the problem too.

[image]

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #1e155e;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

main {
  padding: 20px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Temp</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Temp</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="data.html">Data</a></li>
      <li><a href="lesson.html">Lesson</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <!-- Add your content here -->
    <h2>Welcome to Our Data Provider Site</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla et iaculis arcu. Duis sed nulla eu enim ullamcorper ultricies.</p>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>&copy; 2023 . All rights reserved.</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```